# How to convert string series into integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One of the columns of a pandas data frame contains values such as 0, 'a', 'b'.
This column is parsed as a string. Now I want to convert it to integer to get 0, 1, 2. How can I do this?

Comment: show us some code approach please

Comment: Can you show a representative sample of your data, your attempts and desired output, your explanation is too basic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some initial data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0, 'a', 'b', 'a']})

>>> df
  col
0   0
1   a
2   b
3   a
```

You can create a dictionary of items you'd like to replace:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Then, apply `get` to the column, returning the original value if it is not in the dictionary:

```
df['col'] = df.col.apply(lambda x: d.get(x, x))
>>> df
df
   col
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    1
```

@EdChum If all of the unique items contained in the series are in the dictionary keys, then `.map(d)` is more than five times as fast.  However, any missing value appears as a `NaN`.  Using a `lambda` function with `get` on the dictionary appears to have virtually identical performance.

```
%%timeit df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0, 'a', 'b', 'a'] * 100000})
df['col'] = df.col.map(d)

10 loops, best of 3: 33.3 ms per loop

>>> df.head()
   col
0  NaN
1    1
2    2
3    1
4  NaN
%%timeit df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0, 'a', 'b', 'a'] * 100000})
df['col'] = df.col.apply(lambda x: d.get(x, x))

10 loops, best of 3: 188 ms per loop

%%timeit df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0, 'a', 'b', 'a'] * 100000})
df['col'] = df.col.map(lambda x: d.get(x, x))

10 loops, best of 3: 188 ms per loop

In [64]: %timeit df['col'] = df.col.map(d)
10 loops, best of 3: 36.1 ms per loop
```

And here's the crazy part.  I tested this a few lines of code earlier and got different results:

```
%%timeit df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0, 'a', 'b', 'a'] * 100000})
df['col'] = df.col.map(d)

10 loops, best of 3: 33.4 ms per loop

>>> df.head()
   col
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    0

>>> pd.__version__
'0.16.2'
```

Comment: Use `map` for this, it's cyython-ised: `df[col].map(d)`

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and stupid, because it looks like very simple try this approach:

```
if value == 'a':
   x = 1
if value == 'b':
   x = 2
else:
   x = 0
```